# Selenium - How can I scrape this table?

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape data from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ however it seems that the table's `tr` and `td` kept changing throughout the rows. I have the code below so far and it is not working.

```
public ArrayList<Data>getAllData(){
        ArrayList<Data>allData = new ArrayList<Data>();
        try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebDriver browser = load();
        int row = browser.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr")).size();
        int col = browser.findElements(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td")).size();
        for ( int i = 3; i < row; i++) {
            for ( int j = 1; j < col; j++) {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setId(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setCountry(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalCases(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setNewCases(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalDeaths(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setNewDeaths(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalRecovered(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setActiveCases(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setSeriousCases(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalCasesPerMillionPop(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalDeathsPerMillionPop(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTotalTests(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
        data.setTestsPerMillion(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());       
        allData.add(data);
            }
        }
        browser.quit();
        browser.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return allData;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're currently doing is finding all the elements that match row and column - but then you're navigating the index location on the table as opposed the actual elements you found.

If you look at the table body in dev tools you can see it contains total rows that are hidden from view. USA is row 3 (highlighted in devtools) but rows 4, 5 and 6 are totals.
[image: devtools]

If you expand then out the column numbers and content vary.

Couple of things to suggest:

Try a smarter xpath to get all rows:  (this seems to skip those headers)

```
//table[@id="main_table_countries_today"]//tr[@role="row"]
```

Then, iterate the row elements you found with a foreach loop (not by xpath index).
And, inside that loop, get the td tags within each row.

For example:

```java
public void GettingAllTheData(){

            //Get all the ROWS that match
            var rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='main_table_countries_today']//tr[@role='row']"));

            //loop all rows
            for (var row : rows) {
                //Then get the columns within the row object!
                var cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

                //replace this with writing out your data 
                //this is jut to make sure it writes out as expected. 
                //You might not need a second loop 
                for (var col : cols)
                {
                    System.out.println(col.getText());
                }
            }
    }
```

I didn't want to recreate your data object so i just went with print. For me this seems to consistently write the results.

First iteration:

```
1
USA
3,619,643
+2,816
140,200
+56
1,646,683
1,832,760
16,459
10,933
423
44,867,389
135,518
331,081,677
```

Second iteration:

```
2
Brazil
1,972,072
+1,163
75,568
+45
1,366,775
529,729
8,318
9,275
355
4,911,063
23,098
212,620,008
```

Comment: Thank you that works. Do you have a tool to generate those kind of xpaths? I've seen it around but the tool I use always show the ones I listed in the question

Comment: You don't need a tool mate. Takes seconds to do it by hand. This is a great learning resource : https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/